# Detect if device has microphone/camera in PHP

Tags: php

I know this can be done in Javascript, I've seen it on projects like these: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/DetectRTC/

I just need to detect if the device viewing my website has a microphone/camera and do an if statement on it, but in PHP.

How would this be possible?

Comment: You must detect it in the client side with Javascript, and send the info to your server via http/ajax request. There is no way to detect that just with PHP.